# Exibir postagem após as 6 últimas

Tags: wordpress, slider

Olá, estou com uma dúvida na condição do construtor da classe WP_query() do wordpress

No topo do blog eu tenho um loop mostrando em um slider jquery as ultimas 6 postagens do blog

```
  $query1 = new WP_Query( "showposts=6" );
  while ( $query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
```

até aí correto, mas no corpo do blog eu gostaria de exibir apenas as postagens que vieram antes, ou seja.. as 6 últimas no slider e as demais no blog listando os posts

O problemas é que se eu colocar a ordem ascendente ele pega as postagens antigas em primeiro lugar no corpo do blog

```
$query2 = new WP_Query( "order=ASC&showposts=+6" );
while ( $query2->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
```

Os posts com os ID's ficam da seguinte manteira no slider:
**ID 10 - ID 9 - ID 8 - ID 7 - ID 6 - ID 5 - ID 4**

E no blog: 
**ID: 1
ID: 2
ID: 3**

Entenda cada ID como uma postagem

Answer (score 0):

Se você não precisa se preocupar com paginação, `offset` resolve:

```
$query2 = new WP_Query( "showposts=6&offset=6" );
while ( $query2->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post();
```

`offset=6` faz a query pular os primeiros 6 posts e pegar os próximos seis.

--

Se precisa da paginação na parte inferior, você pode pegar os IDs da primeira query e excluir da seguinda:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( "showposts=6" );
$query1_IDs = wp_list_pluck( $query1->posts, 'ID' );
$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 'showposts' => 6, 'post__not_in' => $query1_IDs ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer um contador e só printar a partir do 6

```
while(suas condições){
for(i=0;i>=6;i++){ seu echo }
}
```

vê se isso te ajuda ;)